# Integrating a custom bootstrap navigation menu (custom ids/classes) into Wordpress (wp_nav_menu)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-walker

I am having a hell of a time with this one issue.  Everything but this has worked great for me, so hoping I can get some feedback.  I designed a static website using twitter bootstrap and made quite a few alterations to the structure.  Converting it over to a dynamic wordpress theme.  I have a navbar-left and navbar-right ul because on larger sizes (sm-lg) the logo appears in the center of my navigation bar, with 3 links on the left and 3 links on the right.

All works great, except when I try and apply my styles to the generated wp_nav_menu.  I don't really understand this part of it so hoping for a simple explanation out there.  I have tried adding the custom css to the menu (added it to each menu item basically in Wordpress) with no success.  I also understand that nav walker will need to be installed which is no problem.  Below is the HTML for it:

```
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

            <div id="navbar-collapse-main" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="left-side-nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a class="nav-links" href="page-home.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-links" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-links" href="#">Drink Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-links" href="#">Food Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-links" href="#">Specials</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Order</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /#left-side-nav -->

                <ul id="right-side-nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Catering</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /#right-side-nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- /#main-nav -->
```

and here is the wp_nav_menu

```
            <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'        => 'primary',
                'container'             => 'nav', 
                'container_id'          => 'navbar-collapse-main',
                'container_class'       => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'menu_class'            => 'navbar-right navbar-left'
                ) );
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of this function are almost all strings, so as far as I know you can't use it to call two menus at once.

What I would do is something like this:

```
<div id="navbar-collapse-main" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'        => 'YOUR_MENU_ID',
                'menu_id'     => 'left-side-nav',
                'menu_class'  => 'navbar-left'
            ) );
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'        => 'YOUR_MENU_ID',
                'menu_id'     => 'right-side-nav',
                'menu_class'  => 'navbar-right'
            ) );
?>
</div>
```

And you can habilitate the option "CSS Classes" in the "Screen options" in the Menu admin page, and than you can add custom classes to your menu items.

Comment: I went back and added:

 <div id="navbar-collapse-main" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <?php 
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_id'      => 'navbar-collapse-main',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
      to both arrays and put them between the navbar-collapse-main div, looks like it is applying the font size but not the positioning, text-decoration, etc

Comment: The suggestion worked as far as getting the menu to work properly.  The only issue I am having is the link styles are not working properly.  nav-links and dropdown-links to be particular.  Google font is not applying to it, color/hover color not applying

Comment: you can try to edit your CSS to something like this: instead of using the class **nav-links** use navbar-nav > li > a, and instead of **dropdown-links** use .dropdown-menu > li > a. or you can add this classes with javascript

Comment: i don't know if you notice, but the custom classes are added to the **li** tag, so you have to edit your CSS anyway

Comment: They are added to the anchor tags.  I finally figured it out, thanks!